# Cygwin cigstart and mintty not writing tail -f piped to grep to file

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to create a .sh file that runs a process and then writes some of the logging output to a separate file.  I have pretty much everything working except for a way to get cygwin to actually write to the file.  Both of the following display a new cygwin window and seem to follow the log file but neither write to the output file:

```
cygstart tail -f ./logs/full-log.txt | grep --line-buffered "LOG_FILE:" > ./logs/lrp-log.txt
mintty tail -f ./logs/full-log.txt | grep --line-buffered "LOG_FILE:" > ./logs/lrp-log.txt
```

The following works, but I would like to incorporate this into my larger script so I need someway of getting it to run in the background so my script can continue on.

```
tail -f ./logs/full-log.txt | grep --line-buffered "LOG_FILE:" > ./logs/lrp-log.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that

```
cygstart tail -f ./logs/full-log.txt | grep --line-buffered "LOG_FILE:" > ./logs/lrp-log.txt
```

means:

```
{ cygstart tail -f ./logs/full-log.txt; } | grep --line-buffered "LOG_FILE:" > ./logs/lrp-log.txt
```

i.e. you're running:

```
{ cygstart tail } | grep
```

instead of what you're trying to do:

```
cygstart { tail  | grep }
```

If you're just trying to modify a shell script to put `tail | grep` in the background then this is probably all you really need:

```
( tail -f ./logs/full-log.txt | grep --line-buffered "LOG_FILE:" > ./logs/lrp-log.txt; ) &
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly for what I was trying to do.  I went with the last solution you suggested (running the process in the background by putting the & at the end of the line).